# C++ Passing construction of derived object to function expecting base in clang

Tags: c++, clang++

Simplest example:

```
struct A {};
struct B : public A {};
void Call(A&) {}
int main() { Call(B()); return 0; }
```

This goes through in MSVC. This doesn't go through with clang 7.0.0-3:

```
test.cpp:4:14: error: no matching function for call to 'Call'
int main() { Call(B()); return 0; }
             ^~~~
test.cpp:3:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'B' to 'A &' for 1st argument
void Call(A&) {}
     ^
```

Why?

I would've expected the constructor to be called, the object being kept in memory by main(), the reference being honored for the function call, and then the object being destroyed once the Call() function is executed. Instead, it simply doesn't compile.

Comment: MSVC doesn't like it either live: https://godbolt.org/z/YkM3JP

Comment: See the dupe for why this works on MSVS.  You need `void Call(const A&)` to be portable.

Comment: In this case, I couldn't make it const& as it needs to be modified, I expect my behaviour to be executed in the destructor. It makes sense it's weird, though.

Comment: @RichardCritten EDIT: Played with godbolt. It's because I am calling the compiler directly, while the instance you provided has the "/W4 /permissive-" parameters. Remove these and it goes through.

Comment: Try with /permissive-  see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=vs-2019

Comment: Exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you are trying to work with MS extensions I think those 2 switches should normally be required.

Comment: Agreed! Well, what I worked on has it. And building with the command prompt without argument has it. So for me, it was a clang vs msvc. That said, the end result is pretty much this is not allowed because Stoustrup saw it as evil, not because this is technically invalid code. There's actual exception in code to make it not work.